# pyparsing: parsing nested C-style comments verbatim

Tags: pyparsing

I'm working on a parser/code transformer for a simple command language (Visual TrueType). It uses C-style comments, but accepts nesting them. `pyparsing.cStyleComment` chokes on that, so I'm looking for something else.

Input looks like (note that everything is commented out):

```
/* VTTTalk glyph 1023, char 0xffff */
/* GUI generated Tue Jul 08 15:52:37 2014 */

/* Y direction 
YAnchor(255)
YDist(305,433,>=)
[...]

/* X direction */

Smooth()
*/
```

I'd like to get the following parsed output with spacing/newlines inside the comments intact:

```
["/* VTTTalk glyph 1023, char 0xffff */",
 "/* GUI generated Tue Jul 08 15:52:37 2014 */",
 "/* Y direction\nYAnchor(255)\nYDist(305,433,>=)\n[...]\n\n/* X direction */\n\nSmooth()\n*/"]
```

So far, I can at least keep the general structure with `nestedExpr(opener="/*", closer="*/")` and attach a parse action that (recursively) generates a C-style comment string, but that loses the comment's formatting. Is there a canonical way to do it?

Comment: Wrap your `nestedExpr` with `originalTextFor`, which will return the original text from the input string. If `<TAB>`s are important, be sure to call `expr.parseWithTabs`.on your top level parser expression to preserve `<TAB>`s, otherwise they will be converted to spaces.

Comment: Thanks! Why did you comment instead of replying, though? I can't seem to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: I don't want to discourage other pyparsing users from answering by hogging all the pyparsing answer rep. You can write this up as a self-answer, and then after a couple day timeout accept it as the answer.